# display image in gridview column based on value in other column

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview

I have a gridview which has a checkbox column and an image column

now if the checkbox is selected the image column should show a green tick image and if checkbox is not checked it should show a wrong image icon in consecutive rows.

the .aspx page has

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Backup Session Status" 
             SortExpression="backupsessionstatus">
             <EditItemTemplate>
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
                     Checked='<%# Bind("backupsessionstatus") %>' />
             </EditItemTemplate>
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
                     Checked='<%# Bind("backupsessionstatus") %>' Enabled="false" />
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>



         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Backup Session Status">
             <EditItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             </EditItemTemplate>
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"/>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
```

and the .cs file is:

```
 foreach (GridViewRow myRow in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                Image img1 = (Image)myRow.FindControl("Image1");
                CheckBox chkbox1 = (CheckBox)myRow.FindControl("CheckBox1");
                if (chkbox1.Checked)
                {
                    img1.ImageUrl = "greenimage.jpg";
                }
                else
                {
                    img1.ImageUrl = "redimage.jpg";
                }
            }
```

it is not displaying no image in the column

please suggest a way...
thanks

Comment: "show a wrong image icon in consecutive rows"? Do you mean consecutive column or row? You code suggested 'column'. The cs codes posted, which event is it tied to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the inputs but i got the answer.. this is how

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Backup Session Status" 
         SortExpression="backupsessionstatus">
         <EditItemTemplate>
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
                 Checked='<%# Bind("backupsessionstatus") %>' />
         </EditItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
                 Checked='<%# Bind("backupsessionstatus") %>' Enabled="false" />
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>



     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Backup Session Status">
         <EditItemTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         </EditItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/NewFolder1/1258341827_tick.png"/>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is the .CS code

```
foreach (GridViewRow myRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            Image img1 = (Image)myRow.FindControl("Image1");
            CheckBox chkbox1 = (CheckBox)myRow.FindControl("CheckBox1");
            if (chkbox1.Checked)
            {
                img1.ImageUrl = "~/greenimage.jpg";
            }
            else
            {
                img1.ImageUrl = "~/redimage.jpg";
            }
        }
```

I learnt that you have to give a imageurl in the aspx page and then modify it to any image in the code behind. if you dont give the image url in the aspx page it wont work...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not true.

Answer (score 1):

Have you stepped through the code in debug and ensured your `foreach` routine is running as you expect it to? Always check the obvious first... are your image paths correct? no "/" will mean it is looking for the image relative to the folder the page is loaded in.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the image url in the `OnRowDataBound` event of the `GridView`.

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
    if (chk != null)
    {
        Image img1 = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("Image1");
        if (chk.Checked)
            img1.ImageUrl = "greenimage.jpg";
        else
            img1.ImageUrl =  "redimage.jpg";
    }
}
```