# display image in column of gridview based on condition

Tags: c#

Hi i am having a gridview with 6 columns in which my first column is check box . I want to insert an image beside the check box so that whenever there is some error in validation with regards to that row the image should be displayed if there is no error than the image should not be displayed.How to do this.Please help me out thanks in advance.

Comment: Logic is going to be in the initializeRow event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [display image in gridview column based on value in other column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739292/display-image-in-gridview-column-based-on-value-in-other-column)

Comment: but i want both image and my checkbox to be in same column in grid sorry if i was asking in wrong way i am very new bee to this technology so please help

Comment: At what point does your validation occur? Is there a Submit button or something similar? At any rate, whenever your validation occurs, that's when you want to do this. So if you have a Button_Click event, you'll do your validation checking and change the image accordingly. But to really answer your question, we need more info. How are you doing validation and when does it occur?

Comment: Hi melanie we are having submit button. on clicking on submit if we are not filling any of the columns we get validation error of that particular field but in my case whenever i get error i need to see image on the first column of my row which is already having check box.

Comment: So on button click we are checking for validations so if the validation are wrong than an image should pop up on first column of the row

Comment: Is this ASP.Net or winforms or....?

Comment: its asp.net and using server side validation

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below should do it. In your aspx file create a TemplateField

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header" >
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbWhatever" ></asp:CheckBox>
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="img1" ImageUrl="~/filename1" Visible="false"/>
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="img2" ImageUrl="~/filename2" Visible="false"//>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then in code behind, when you do your validation, depending on your validation results either do:

```
Image img = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("img1");
img1.Visible = true;
```

or

```
Image img = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("img2");
img2.Visible = true;
```